# Translate and View Inventor Files in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to load Inventor projects into my Bucket and display them in the Forge Viewer.
For this I downloaded the Inventor example project (Jet Engine Model).
I want to view it in the Forge Viewer just like here (https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/).

I can upload single parts (.ipt) of the project onto my bucket without any problems. But I want to upload and view the whole project (like i do with Revit projects).

When I save the Inventor project as "Pack and Go" and upload the .zip file I get an error message:

```
{ 
status code: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
  statusBody:
   { diagnostic: 'Failed to trigger translation for this file. } 
}
```

Uploading .zip files of Revit (.rvt) or 3D Max (.f3d) Projects works fine.

Unfortunately I have not found anything suitable for this, so I am writing here now.
Is there an example project where I can see how to view whole Inventor projects in the Forge Viewer without linking every .ipt part manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the Inventor "Pack and Go" feature builds the zip file, but please note that when sending zip files to Model Derivative service for translation, the main design file must not be in any subfolder. The contents of the archive could look like this:

```
- inventor-project.zip
  - root-design-file.iam
  - some-part-1.ipt
  - subfolder
    - some-part-2.ipt
    - some-part-3.ipt
```

In this case, the payload to the [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) endpoint should look like this:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "<urn of your zip file>",
        "compressedUrn": true,
        "rootFilename": "root-design-file.iam"
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf",
                "views": [
                    "2d",
                    "3d"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: My faults. It works perfectly. I just entered the wrong "rootFilename".
Thanks for the support!

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!